# iam trying to install geant4 on ubuntu and there is cmake error modules

Tags: cmake

CMake Error at
/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146
(message):
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393
(_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:310
(FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
environments/g4py/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)

Comment: As you could guess, the message "Could NOT find PythonLibs" means that CMake cannot find Python libraries. Do you have them installed? Good questions are rarely consist solely from the error message. Please, add to the question post all relevant information. See also [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.